# How to set name for a checkbox in react jsx

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, jsx

I'm trying to set the name in a checkbox input but it seems it doesn't work:

```
const DepartmentRow = ({ data }) =>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ListOfDepartments" value={data.department}/>
      <span>{data.departament}</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>;

DepartmentRow.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.object
};
```

In data I receive an user object that has a department. If I write:

```
<td>{data.department}</td>
```

it works and it displays the name of the department, so I receive the right information on data.

This is what I got for the moment:
[image]

And I want this:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your input div is taking the whole space. Try to use a single div with `display:inline-block` and place both `input` and `span` inside it.

Comment: @Scusf0 Try to inspect elements with the chrome dev tools and fiddle with the css there.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a typo in your code, did you try to call `data.department` instead of `data.departament` ?

The following works for me

```
const DepartmentRow = () => {
    const data = {
        department: 'Production',
    }
    return(
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="ListOfDepartments" value={data.department}/>
                <span>{data.department}</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    )
}
```